# Non-normality in panel data

Tags: normality-assumption, fixed-effects-model

I am checking for normality after my fixed effects regression. According to the `K-density` graphs, the distribution looks normal but when I do the S-Wilk command, residuals are non-normal.

I am posting the output below.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Do you think the problem needs to be corrected for since I have to do hypothesis testing? If Yes, do I use bootstrapped errors? What is the command for the latter?

Comment: The kernel density plots are over-optimistic here as they smooth the distribution towards something better behaved. A better plot if you really want to check normality is a quantile-quantile plot: in Stata that's `qnorm`. In practice, I wouldn't take the P-values as evidence of anything to worry about.

Comment: @nix cox: Okay so for the 1st regression thers's no problem according to kdensity as well as swilk. But i want to make sure I fix the other two. So i've pasted the qnorm plots here. If I dont use bootstrap and normality is not really a problem as the deviation is not major, how do I justify such low p-values in my paper? I actually ran the 2nd regression with bootstrap and my results became insignificant so i am concerned.

Comment: S-W tells you there's evidence for non-normality but how are you going to use that signal to improve your model? That's the key question. I don't see that any one can comment on your analysis as a whole; we can just see some details on residuals.  Also, much depends on exactly how you bootstrap. I don't know enough on the specifics of panel models to advise more.

Answer (score -1):

Considering your p-values yes, your data does need to be corrected for. Run through the bootstrapped errors and that should correct the data... edit your question if that doesn't work and I'll look into it more.

Comment: @DaveRowanThanks. Whats the command for bootstrap..vce..? the exact format? And after running bootstrap will the swilk test work again to see if the problem is corrected

Comment: Bootstrapping doesn't really "correct the data". Its main role here is to provide alternative standard errors.

Comment: vce(bootstrap (_b[age] - _b[wks_work]),rep(10) seed(123)) I believe this would be an example but with your variables not mine.

Comment: Okay. And another thing to confirm...Besides giving alternative standard errors, does bootstrap also correct for heteroscedasticity. And what about serial correlation or cross section dependance. If it doesn't then will Stata allows the usage of other commands like xtserial after bootsrap?

Comment: And a relevant question: How do we decide how many rep to do with bootstrap? ANy criteria? Thanks

Comment: @Danny Please note that asking specifically about Stata commands is off-topic here.

Comment: I think the rep depends on size of your data not too sure if there is a specific criteria...